# Comparing data from 2 files by tokenization

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm reading 2 files: one named `myFile`, and the other named `dictionary`.

In dictionary, there is 2 value for each of the word in it.
So, I read the sentence in `myFile`, and tokenize them to sort out the value for each word.

My code is running as below:

```
      while ((text = file.readLine()) != null){//read myFile content line by line
            ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<String>();
            StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(text);//split line content
            while (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String token = str.nextToken();
                content.add(token);
            }//create an array to store the content of line

            //define subjective of each line
            boolean subjective = false;

            //compare from file content with SentiWordNet
            for (int i=0; i<content.size(); i++){
                String cont = content.get(i);

                while((line = csv.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    //read line from SentiWordNet
                    String[] data = line.split("\t");

                    //read data SentiWordnet
                    String sentiWord = data[4];

                    if (sentiWord.contains(cont)){                              
                        if (data[2] != "0" || data[3] != "0")
                            subjective = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println(subjective);     
        }
```

`file` is `myFile` with sentence, and `csv` is the `dictionary`.
The problem now is that only the 1st token in the `myFile` carry out the comparison, while others do not.

Any idea how to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are not closing the dictionary.  This line of code:

```
            while((line = csv.readLine()) != null)
```

Will start to fail once you get to the end of the dictionary the first time (i.e. for the first word in myFile).  For subsequent words, it will fail immediately, because you haven't closed/reopened the file.

**EDIT:**

In looking at your code, you are trying to determine if a word is subjective by reading each sentence in `myFile` and looping over each word in the sentence, and for each such word, reading `dictionary`.  If your `myFile` contains many sentences and words, you will be reading the dictionary (which is likely large) many times, which seems inefficient.

For example, if there are `s` sentences, each with `w` words, you will be opening, and reading the entire dictionary `s*n` times.

Alternatively, what you could do read in the entire `myFile` into an array of sentences of length `s`, or even into an array of words of length `n*w`.  This will take memory on the order of `n*w` (your current algorithm takes only `w` memory since you are creating a single array to store the words in a sentence, and re-use this array for each sentence).  Then, read in the dictionary once, and for each word in the dictionary, see if it is in the array of words/sentences.

A better approach which costs more memory (assuming your dictionary is bigger than `myFile`) might be to read the entire dictionary into memory and sort it.  Then, read `myFile` and locate each word in your in-memory dictionary using an efficient search.  Should be much faster, assuming your files are large.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, actually the previous code was in hasmap, but I totally have no idea about the sturcture of hashmap, btw this problem solved, thanks for your help